# Cannot search application on specific device in Google Play store

Tags: android, size, screen

I published android application on Google play store,
I can search application Google play store at most of device including GalaxyS4, but cannot search it on Galaxy S5.

My manifest include supports-screens like this

```
<supports-screens
     android:anyDensity="true"
     android:largeScreens="true"
     android:normalScreens="true"
     android:smallScreens="true"
     android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

and excluded the device Galaxy tablet 10.1 series on google play store.
How can I solve the problem? Is there any other thing I should check?

Comment: post the whole manifest

Comment: Include your permissions, it sounds like you need a permission for a hardware that the tablet don't have.